# How does this add up?

Tags: java, sum, addition

```java
public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char a='3';
        int b=011;
        System.out.println(a+b);
    }
}
```

The answer turns out to be 60 but I don't understand how.
Could anyone please explain.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Character 3 is encoded as 51. 011 is octal for 9. 51 + 9 = 60

Answer (score 3):

First, `char` + `int` is an `int`. So you're widening the `char` `'3'` to `int` `51`. Second, numbers with a leading `0` are in octal. So `011` is another way to write decimal `9`. `51 + 9 = 60`, or

```
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", (int) a, b, a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow! Hope a good trip!
when you add a `char` and an `int`, it will output an `int`. In the situation, the `char` will be explained into its ASCIIhttps://www.ascii-code.com/ value, so '3' is 51. 011 is an octal number so it will be explained as 1 * 8 + 1 = 9. So, 51+9 = 60.